# Calculating mean values along masking numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d NumPy array:

```
# x, y, z, mask_id
data = np.array([[ 3.28246069,  3.63800144, -1.66515279,  0],
                 [ 3.28246069,  3.63800144, -1.66515279,  0],
                 [ 0.,  0., 0.,  1]])
```

This is the result what I expect:

```
# mean value of each mask id
array([[3.28246069,  3.63800144, -1.66515279], [0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to calculate mean value from same mask id. Is there any fast method?

Comment: What do you mean by mask_id?

Comment: I think you need more example input and output, it's not clear how you arrive at this result. And please make sure your code examples run.

Comment: looks like OP want the mean for each group of the last value